# What is the right way to perform 64-bit arithmetic?

Tags: agda

I've found primitives for 64-bit floating point and 32-bit signed integer operations. I've not found primitives for 64-bit unsigned integer operations. Without those, what is the correct way to deal with 64-bit uint arithmetic on Agda?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be [present on `2.5.4`](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). (Exactly one version above the one I was using.)

> Added support for built-in 64-bit machine words.
>
> These are defined in Agda.Builtin.Word and come with two primitive operations to convert to and from natural numbers.
>
> ```
> Word64 : Set
> primWord64ToNat   : Word64 → Nat
> primWord64FromNat : Nat → Word64
> ```
>
> Converting to a natural number is the trivial embedding, and converting from a natural number gives you the remainder modulo 2^64. The proofs of these theorems are not primitive, but can be defined in a library using primTrustMe.
>
> Basic arithmetic operations can be defined on Word64 by converting to natural numbers, peforming the corresponding operation, and then converting back. The compiler will optimise these to use 64-bit arithmetic. For instance,
>
> ```
> addWord : Word64 → Word64 → Word64
> addWord a b = primWord64FromNat (primWord64ToNat a + primWord64ToNat b)
>
> subWord : Word64 → Word64 → Word64
> subWord a b = primWord64FromNat (primWord64ToNat a + 18446744073709551616 - primWord64ToNat b)
> ```
>
> These compiles (in the GHC backend) to addition and subtraction on Data.Word.Word64